# Working with modbus rtu and reading holding values in c#

Tags: c#, serial-port, modbus

I have been working on serial communication for a few days. I have seen many tutorials on it and tried to implement it. I am able to connect to the `COM` port and send and receive data.

```
 private void sendData()
        {
        bool error = false;
        if (rdText.Checked == true)        //if text mode is selected, send data as tex
            {
            // Send the user's text straight out the port 
            ComPort.Write(txtSend.Text );

            // Show in the terminal window 
            rtxtDataArea.ForeColor = Color.Green;    //write sent text data in green colour              
            txtSend.Clear();                       //clear screen after sending data

            }
        else                    //if Hex mode is selected, send data in hexadecimal
            {
            try
                {
                // Convert the user's string of hex digits (example: E1 FF 1B) to a byte array
                byte[] data = HexStringToByteArray(txtSend.Text);

                // Send the binary data out the port
              ComPort.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                // Show the hex digits on in the terminal window
              rtxtDataArea.ForeColor = Color.Blue;   //write Hex data in Blue
              rtxtDataArea.AppendText(txtSend.Text.ToUpper() + "\n");
              txtSend.Clear();                       //clear screen after sending data
                }
            catch (FormatException) { error = true; }

                // Inform the user if the hex string was not properly formatted
                catch (ArgumentException) { error = true; }

            if (error) MessageBox.Show(this, "Not properly formatted hex string: " + txtSend.Text + "\n" + "example: E1 FF 1B", "Format Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);

            }
        }
```

Now I want to do it using `Modbus RTU Library`. I have searched it and found out some libraries but their tutorials are not that much understandable i.e. They are not that much clear how the library is working. For now, I just want to make a request frame like below

1. Device ID
2. Holding Register
3. Register Value
4. Checksum (Not clear that whether the library will set it or I have to set it manually)

Is there any good tutorial on it that how can I just make a simple request?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to send data by comport.
The problem is "how to write a modbus rtu request".

You may check Modbus organization's [documentation](http://modbus.org/docs/PI_MBUS_300.pdf)

Example: Read two holding register from 0x0001 and 0x0002 from a ID 11 (0x0B) device.

```
Slave Address       0B
Function            03
Starting Address Hi 00
Starting Address Lo 01
No. of Points Hi    00
No. of Points Lo    02
CRC Hi              95
CRC Lo              61
```

You may check crc from this crc [generating site](https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation)
Besure checking "Hex" and look at CRC16 (modbus).

Following sample data is displayed as following.

```
byte[] data = new byte[] {
0x11, 0x03, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x95, 0x61 
};
```

By sending this data , you may get respond by following data structure.

```
Field Name              (Hex)
Slave Address            0B
Function                 03
Byte Count               06
Data Hi (Register 0x01)  00
Data Lo (Register 0x01)  2B
Data Hi (Register 0x02)  00
Data Lo (Register 0x02)  13
Error Check (LRC or CRC) ––
```

PS: Between each request, you need a silent interval for 28 bits,  you may calculate the silent interval by baud rate.

Comment: I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772162/handling-modbus-rtu-frame-in-c-sharp) related to it can you please see it ?